# Need someone who can read deleted comments

Tags: discussion

I am not sure if I said something really stupid in response to this question

[How does "if p, then q" compare to "p only if q"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/96568/how-does-if-p-then-q-compare-to-p-only-if-q)

dunno if it would be a typo (I tend to think of them as identical) or a moment's confusion. Anyway, can someone post the comment I deleted?

It may seem a bit OCD to care! But I'm curious if I got that confused, and cannot recall.

---

I think I recall saying they were opposites but said the same thing, which is confusing, unless I commented that they express necessity and an inverse sufficiency.

Sorry for the OCD request, but I'd appreciate a copy and paste!

---

I've proven to myself that I don't tend to make that mistake, but I'm still intrigued. Anyway, not made to feel very welcome, so I'll delete again.

Comment: * be from a typo.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain: I will never know.

Comment: I think this is technically the correct answer haha.